# Changing Tabs in a Tab Control does not send Child a Message

Tags: winforms, tabcontrol

In a C# Windows Forms application using Framework 2.X, clicking on a tab control does not send a message to the child controls (such as a lost focus event).  Using Microsoft Spy++, I do not see messages sent to my child control.  I do get messages when I click back on the tab hosting the control.

Any ideas on what I need to do to have my child control know that its not displayed after the tab was changed.  I would like the code to be in the control, not the parent.  I am guessing that I am missing out on some event or registration.

Thanks in advance,

Craig

Answer (score 1):

> I am guessing that I am missing out on some event or registration.

I don't think you are.

The a lost focus event would be too soon since it happens before the page changes.

The Child Control's [VisibleChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.visiblechanged%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) event only fires when the parent TabPage is shown and not when it is hidden which is not what you want.

You can handle either the [TabPage.VisibleChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabpage.visiblechanged%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) or the [TabControl.SelectedIndexChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.selectedindexchanged%28v=VS.80%29.aspx). This of course is from the Parent not the Child, which is also not what you want.

Incidently I believe the [TCM_SETCURSEL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb760612%28VS.85%29.aspx) message is sent to the control on tab change (again not helping with the "not in the Parent requriement"